# Cartopy problem when plotting NetCDF file

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to display some data with cartopy. I read the NetCDF file with xarray and tried to plot it with the non-rotated coordinates available:

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

dset = xr.open_dataset("tas_EUR-11_IPSL-IPSL-CM5A-MR_rcp85_r1i1p1_GERICS-REMO2015_v1_mon_201101-202012.nc")
tas = dset['tas']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12,5])

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

dset.isel(time=0)['tas'].plot(ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), x='lon', y='lat', 
add_colorbar=False)

ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
plt.show()
```

The problem is I obtain the following plot:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fodnz.jpg)

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if the sample data could be uploaded (if the data is too large, you can output only one time/one level). I wonder if the grid of your data is non-rectangular, and the xarray's plot method may not support the non-rectangular grids very well.